# Complex nested JSON Array from PhP Coding

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have created a JSON file from the database, which has two table semone with attributes id, semester, cname and table courses with attributes coname and credit.

Code I am writing in php is following.

main.php

```
<?php
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "scheduler";

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $database) or die ("Unable to connect"); 


    $query = "SELECT semone.userid AS sbuid, semone.semester AS semester, 
                      semone.cname AS name, courses.credit AS value, 
                      courses.progskill AS skill
              FROM semone
              INNER JOIN courses ON semone.cname = courses.coname" ;

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die ("Unable to connect");

    $info = array();
    $test = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $row['xyz'] = array(
                            'name'=> $row['name'],
                            'value'=> $row['value']    
                           );

        $info[$row['semester']]['children'][]= $row['xyz'];

        $data = json_encode(array('id' => $row['sbuid'], 'children' => $info));
    }
    echo $data;
?>
```

I want to get JSON file as seen in the following code, but I am getting something like this.

**output.json**

```
  {"id":"12345", 
        "children":

        {"first":
        {"children":
        [{"name":"CSE101","value":"100"},
       {"name":"CSE102","value":"100"}]},

        "second":
        {"children":
      [{"name":"CSE103","value":"50"}, 
      {"name":"CSE104","value":"100"},
      {"name":"CSE105","value":"100"}]},

        "third":
        {"children":
        [{"name":"CSE106","value":"50"}]}
         }}
```

But this is what I am expecting.

**expected.json**

```
{
 "id": 12345,
 "children":
  [{
     "semester": "first",
     "children": 
     [{
     "name": "C101","value": 100},
      { "name": "C102","value": 100}]
    }, 
    {
    "semester": "second",
      "children": 
      [{
     "name": "C103", "value": 50}, 
     {"name": "C104","value": 100}, 
     {"name": "C105","value": 100}]
}, 
{
 "semester": "third",
 "children":  
  [{"name": "C106","value": 50}]
 }
}
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please have a look into it. I need it but not able to solve it.

Comment: You are no where near it, for a start I assume you will be getting data for multiple users as you add no limit to your query. But you have no code to cope with more than one student or more than one semester per student. SO **is not a free coding resource** You are basically asking someone to write your code but without even properly explaining your requirements or your database structure. _Trapper would be very annoyed with you_

Comment: @RiggsFolly I got your point and basically that will be the end thing but as I am new to programming so thought of proceeding step by step. May be to get the data for single student first and then for multiple students. May be I am going in the wrong direction. Sorry had no idea of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your while loop with:

```
$lastId = null;
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $row['xyz'] = array(
                        'name'=> $row['name'],
                        'value'=> $row['value']    
                       );

    $info[$row['semester']]['semester'] = $row['semester'];
    $info[$row['semester']]['children'][]= $row['xyz'];

    $lastId = $row['sbuid'];
}

// do not call json_encode on each iteration of the loop
$data = json_encode(array('id' => $lastId, 'children' => array_values($info)));
```

**EXPLENATION**

You're expecting `$row['semester']` to be an field of `children`'s object, but you're setting this value as a key. You need to explicitly set this value with `semester` key (parallely to deep `children` array) and use `array_values` to remove keys before encoding (associative arrays are encoded as objects, while numeric ones as arrays).

Also I don't get the idea of saving only the last `$row['sbuid']` in your JSON, maybe you wanted to do something different here?

Read more about PHP's [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), and [json encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: ID thing is to separate the different students with their ID's since the id thing is outside while loop so not able to get the value from the database and is returning "null" value. For achieving the purpose,I think "id" should be used within the while loop only then we can fetch it from the database and return the exact value.